# Why would I buy a website template when I could just copy the source code?

Tags: html, css, templates, web

There are many websites out there selling HTML templates to use for your own website.
I've bought many web templates in the past, but it just dawned on me;

Most of them offer full previews of the websites they are selling - essentially offering the product for free, since one can just use "View Source Code" and copy-paste the HTML, CSS, JS, et al. into their own program.

I just tried it out myself with [this theme from Themeforest](http://www.26four79.com/ThemeForest/Corporate%20Theme/) and I was able to copy most of the site from the preview (some parts are a bit messy).

My question is: are there functionalities that are impossible to get without buying the website, or is it all just essentially running on the honor system?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about buying website templates, not programming.

Comment: Presumably, the $15-25 that most themes cost is significantly cheaper than the few hours you'll spend getting the copy+pasted theme integrated into your CMS.  It's also significantly cheaper than the copyright lawsuit you may face.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any PHP site you cannot copy the PHP code behind it (or any kind of server-side code) which means that contact forms, newsletter subscriptions etc will not work unless you write your own PHP code for them, however everything else works pretty much fine. It is equivalent of downloading something over a torrent or similar. It is illegal, and not to mention unfair to the developers that have spent time creating the template.

Answer (score 1):

If you will just  manually copy and not buying the template from themeforest or other template sites, you won't get any technical support from author and any succeeding updates from the template. I guess it's also a form of piracy.

So, buying premium templates is beneficial to you and to your clients.

Answer (score 0):

Like Benedict Lewis said, you're just copying the static HTML and none of the server side code. You wouldn't be able to use this is WordPress (or whatever CMS the theme is made for). You'd have to manually create new pages, edit them, and and upload them to your site, which is a pain.

Plus you're stealing someone's work which may be copyrighted.